# Can two docker both set host network mode？

Tags: docker

I know docker host network mode, which will let docker share the same network with host machine. It will not need NAT and you can visit the docker by the host ip adress.

My question is if start two docker both with host network mode, what will happened? I found that **their IP addresses are the same**, will their networks conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting host networking generally disables Docker networking.  It's almost never necessary, unless you have a program that can't be configured to listen on a fixed port or you have a program that listens on thousands of ports.

Since it disables Docker networking, containers that use host networking have direct access to the host network devices.  If they set up network listeners, these share a port space with other host-network containers and non-container processes.  You cannot remap ports, limit a port to being visible only to specific interfaces, or directly communicate with other containers if you have the host network.  Containers don't have their own private IP address or port space in host-network mode.

Nothing stops you from starting multiple containers with host networking (in the same way you can start multiple non-container servers on the host directly), but if they try to listen to the same port on the same (host) interface(s), one of them will fail and you'll have to do application-specific reconfiguration to fix it.

Comment: thx! `but if they try to listen to the same port on the same (host) interface(s), one of them will fail ` Regarding the principle of the container host network, do you have relevant information to recommend

Comment: It is _exactly_ the same as running the two servers directly on the host without Docker involved.

Comment: Yes, but why does it not prompt a port conflict when running the socket program? Do you have a definite conclusion on this point